# Special random variables and monotone class theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am currently reading a proof where the $\pi-\lambda$ Lemma and the monotone class theorem are applied to show a certain property for bounded random variables. The author of the book always shows the property for so-called special random variables first, these are random variables that are products of continuous functions tending to zero at infinity evaluated at a discrete set of points, so they are in particular bounded. The thing is that they are neither mentioned in the $\pi-\lambda$ lemma nor in the monotone class theorem. Thus, I am really wondering why the authors introduce them at all, as they are - afais - not important for the proof, but I guess I am missing an important point here.

See below an example where the special random variable $Y$ is introduced and then, there is a proof shown where they first show it for these special $Y$ and then they extend the result via the monotone class theorem.

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that it's easier to show the continuity using this special random variable.